# What permission should I choose for Instagram app if I want to build a post scheduling system?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

The specific use case:

I am trying to build an app that can help schedule posts for Instagram users who connect to it, which seems not available yet for Personal and Business accounts.

But when I check [the related API doc page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing/), it claims it requires `business_management`, which seems to need my app to take Facebook Login for Business. And that would only allow business accounts to access my app.

Am I approaching it in the wrong way? How should I make my app also accessible to personal users?